# Bamboo execute tasks on different machines

Tags: optimization, continuous-integration, bamboo

I have several databases to test a product on. Each database has two sets of tasks that must run in parallel. For each database I run the following two sets of tasks:

`Install -> Startup -> Test1`

`Install -> Startup -> Test2`

So I currently have both Installs in a Stage, both Startups in a Stage and both Tests in a Stage. This looks something like:

`Install1 and Install2` -> `Startup1 and Startup2` -> `Test1 and Test2`

I'd like to add in another task after each Test, which is Email. Email simply checks a sharepoint site to see if either all of our Test1 tests have completed or Test2 tests. It emails only if one or the other has finished. Email must be run on it's own agent on a different machine so as to not allow two identical emails to go out at once.

Additionally, Test1 takes 1 hour to complete and Test2 takes ~6 hours to complete. I'd like to send test1's email without waiting for test2. Then send test2's email later.

I see the following possibilities:

1. Test1 waits for Test2 to complete then both emails go out from the emailing machine.
2. Test1 gets its own Stage, tries to email from the emailing machine. Then Test2 runs and tries to email from the emailing machine. (Note Test1 and Test2 execute sequentially)
3. Test1 and Test2 get their own Stages and the stages execute in parallel, Test1 and Test2 execute in parallel but I can email from the emailing machine whenever a Test finishes

I would love to have #3, but I don't think executing stages simultaneously is possible. Can anyone else think up a way to have emails go out from a different machine immediately after a test completes, while minimizing time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stages do not run in parallel, but Bamboo jobs do (see [How is a Bamboo workflow organised?](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Understanding+the+Bamboo+CI+Server#UnderstandingtheBambooCIServer-HowisaBambooworkfloworganised?) for details). So why don't you set those procedures up as jobs? Also, in the job requirements tab you can set requirements on the agents to run the job, effectively telling Bamboo to run tasks on separate/chosen machines (see [Configuring a job's requirements](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+a+job%27s+requirements) for details).